# Import github project with submodule in Intellij

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I am trying to import [markdown-writer-fx](https://github.com/JFormDesigner/markdown-writer-fx) in intellij IDEA.

I am facing two problems -

1. Here, Flowless & RichTextFX is added as git submodule.
2. It is an eclipse project

I need help cloning and running this app in my pc.

Comment: Importing `build.gradle` should work (Import from the Welcome Screen). Make sure to checkout git submodules as well.

Comment: @CrazyCoder can you please give me the steps. It will be helpful if you kindly walk me through the steps.

Comment: Please clarify on what specific step you have the problem.